# How to decrease watchers inside AngularJS for ng-show with same condition

Tags: angularjs, performance, ng-show

In my HTML code, some `div` will display with the same condition. I set this condition to `ng-show` for each `div`.

```
<div ng-show="sameCondition1">...data1...</div>
...something else...
<div ng-show="sameCondition1">...data2...</div>
...something else...
<div ng-show="sameCondition1">...data3...</div>
```

AngularJS will create 3 watchers for each `ng-show`. It can affect performance. Is there any way to decrease the number of watchers in this case?

Comment: Most of the times `ng-if` is better then `ng-show`/`ng-hide`.

Comment: This seems a little like micro-optimisation. `ng-show` creates a shallow watch, so it shouldn't be very expensive. If you want to optimise performance, eliminate deep watches and use `ng-if` to get rid of parts of the view that aren't needed at the moment where possible.

Comment: @LeThanh, I've updated my answer. Please take a look.

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal: I like your method!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is possible but if you are using AngularJS > 1.3.x and your `someCondition1` does not changes after one iteration then you can use Angular's feature of unregistering the watcher by using `::` like below:

```
<div ng-show="::sameCondition1">...data1...</div>
...something else...
<div ng-show="::sameCondition1">...data2...</div>
...something else...
<div ng-show="::sameCondition1">...data3...</div>
```

Read more on [One-time binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding)

**Update**

Since your condition will update, so my above solution won't work for you. But I've a cleaner solution to reduce the watcher to just 1 using CSS. Here you go:

```
<div class="{{sameCondition1 ? '' : 'hide-similar'}}">
    <div class="similar1">...data1...</div>
    ...something else...
    <div class="similar1">...data2...</div>
    ...something else...
    <div class="similar1">...data3...</div>
</div>
```

Now, define your CSS:

```
.hide-similar .similar1 {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: My condition will update based on user interaction, so one-way binding can not be applied in my case.

Comment: Oh! Then my answer won't help in your case!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-switch` but it depends on the condition - if your conditions depend on a single variable (Example: `a==1, a==2, a==3`). It will reduce the watchers from 3 to 1.